# How to resolve "javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption" in this code

Tags: java, android

I read a lot of stuff explaining how to resolve this kind of exception but i am still unable to resolve this.

My target is :
  1. Encrypt String data using SecretKey and store it into SQLite database. 
  2. read data from SQLite database and decrypt it using the same SecretKey.

This is my class to encrypt and decrypt data in android application (implementation of target 1 & 2). This code is giving exception -- javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption

How can i solve this error ? Any sugestion will be appreciated.. Thanks

```
      public class Cryptography {

    private String encryptedFileName = "Enc_File2.txt";
    private static String algorithm = "AES";
    private static final int outputKeyLength = 256;
    static SecretKey yourKey = null;

    SQLiteDatabase database;
    DBHelper helper;
    Context context;

    //saveFile("Hello From CoderzHeaven testing :: Gaurav Wable");
    //decodeFile();

    public Cryptography (Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        helper = new DBHelper(context);
        database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    }


    public String encryptString(String data) {
        char[] p = { 'p', 'a', 's', 's' };
        //SecretKey yourKey = null;
        byte[] keyBytes = null;
        byte[] filesBytes = null;
        try {
            if(this.yourKey == null) {
                Log.d("key", "instance null");
                Cursor cursor = database.query("assmain", new String[]{"keyAvailability"}, null, null, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("keyAvailability")) == 1) {
                    Log.d("key", "exists in DB");
                    keyBytes = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("key"));
                    cursor.close();
                    filesBytes = encodeFile(keyBytes, data.getBytes());
                } else {
                    Log.d("key", "generating");
                    this.yourKey = generateKey(p, generateSalt().toString().getBytes()); 
                    filesBytes = encodeFile(this.yourKey, data.getBytes());
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("key", "instance exists");
                //yourKey = this.yourKey;
                filesBytes = encodeFile(yourKey, data.getBytes());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new String(filesBytes);
    }

    public String decryptString(String data) {
        String str = null;
        byte[] decodedData = null;
        try {
            Log.d("To decrypt", data);
            if(this.yourKey == null) {
                Log.d("key", "null");
                Cursor cursor = database.query("assmain", new String[]{"keyAvailability"}, null, null, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("keyAvailability")) == 1) {
                    Log.d("key", "exists in DB");
                    byte[] keyBytes = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("key"));
                    cursor.close();
                    decodedData = decodeFile(keyBytes, data.getBytes());
                } else {
                    Log.d("key", "Unavailable");
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Key Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("key", "instance exists");
                decodedData = decodeFile(this.yourKey, data.getBytes());
            }
            decodedData = decodeFile(yourKey, data.getBytes());
            str = new String(decodedData);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str;
    }

    public static SecretKey generateKey(char[] passphraseOrPin, byte[] salt)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        // Number of PBKDF2 hardening rounds to use. Larger values increase
        // computation time. You should select a value that causes computation
        // to take >100ms.
        final int iterations = 1000;

        // Generate a 256-bit key
        //final int outputKeyLength = 256;

        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory
                .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passphraseOrPin, salt, iterations,
                outputKeyLength);
        yourKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
        return yourKey;
    }

    public static SecretKey generateSalt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        // Generate a 256-bit key
        //final int outputKeyLength = 256;

        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        // Do *not* seed secureRandom! Automatically seeded from system entropy.
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGenerator.init(outputKeyLength, secureRandom);
        SecretKey key = keyGenerator.generateKey();
        return key;
    }

    public static byte[] encodeFile(SecretKey yourKey, byte[] fileData)
            throws Exception {
        byte[] data = yourKey.getEncoded();
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(data, 0, data.length,
                algorithm);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(fileData);

        return encrypted;
    }

    public static byte[] encodeFile(byte[] data, byte[] fileData)
            throws Exception {
        //byte[] data = yourKey.getEncoded();
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(data, 0, data.length,
                algorithm);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(fileData);

        return encrypted;
    }

    public static byte[] decodeFile(SecretKey yourKey, byte[] fileData)
            throws Exception {
        byte[] data = yourKey.getEncoded();
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(data, 0, data.length,
                algorithm);
        //Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(fileData);

        return decrypted;
    }

    public static byte[] decodeFile(byte[] data, byte[] fileData)
            throws Exception {
        //byte[] data = yourKey.getEncoded();
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(data, 0, data.length,
                algorithm);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(fileData);

        return decrypted;
    }
    }
```

---

This is error snippet

```
07-01 14:50:48.230: W/System.err(11715): javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption
07-01 14:50:48.230: W/System.err(11715):    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(BaseBlockCipher.java:705)
07-01 14:50:48.230: W/System.err(11715):    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1111)
07-01 14:50:48.230: W/System.err(11715):    at com.cdac.authenticationl3.Cryptography.decodeFile(Cryptography.java:170)
07-01 14:50:48.230: W/System.err(11715):    at com.cdac.authenticationl3.Cryptography.decryptString(Cryptography.java:95)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding for decrypting the file but not while encrypting the file.
Add AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding for the encryption process as well. So it should be

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I used Cipher.getInstance("AES"); for both Encryption and Decryption. Thanks Amey.

But the actual problem was that i converted encrypted byte[] to String in order to save it into SQLite database. This problem solved by adding data in database in byte[] format.
  
Another Query: Android shared preferences doesn't store byte array. what can i do in this case to store data in shared preferences.  I tried to Convert byte[] to string and added to shared preferences, also applied base64 encoding but it doesn't solve the IlleglalBlockSizeException.